# negative binomial model with interaction in R

Tags: r, interaction, poisson

i have fit negative binomial model to my data as follows:

```
> ngbinmodel <- glm.nb( seizure.rate ~ age + treatment, data = epilepsy_reduced)
>     summary(ngbinmodel)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = seizure.rate ~ age + treatment, data = epilepsy_reduced, 
    init.theta = 1.498983674, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3510  -0.8790  -0.4563   0.4328   1.8916  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.0985089  0.5845392   3.590 0.000331 ***
age         -0.0007965  0.0193064  -0.041 0.967092    
treatment   -0.5011593  0.2405658  -2.083 0.037228 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.499) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 71.217  on 57  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 66.875  on 55  degrees of freedom
AIC: 341.12

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.499 
          Std. Err.:  0.362 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -333.119
```

Now I would like to check if i should include the interaction effect between age and treatment. I have found two methods to do it:

```
  > intearaction_nbm<-addterm(ngbinmodel, . ~ . * age,test="Chisq")
            >     summary(intearaction_nbm)
                   Df         AIC             LRT            Pr(Chi)      
             Min.   :1   Min.   :339.1   Min.   :0.9383   Min.   :0.3327  
             1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:339.4   1st Qu.:0.9383   1st Qu.:0.3327  
             Median :1   Median :339.6   Median :0.9383   Median :0.3327  
             Mean   :1   Mean   :339.6   Mean   :0.9383   Mean   :0.3327  
             3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:339.9   3rd Qu.:0.9383   3rd Qu.:0.3327  
             Max.   :1   Max.   :340.2   Max.   :0.9383   Max.   :0.3327  
             NA's   :1                   NA's   :1        NA's   :1
```

and

```
> ngbinmodel_int <- glm.nb( seizure.rate ~ age*treatment, data = epilepsy_reduced)
>     summary(ngbinmodel_int)
glm.nb(formula = seizure.rate ~ age * treatment, data = epilepsy_reduced, 
    init.theta = 1.531539174, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3503  -0.8742  -0.3848   0.3403   1.8508  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    1.51361    0.83920   1.804   0.0713 .
age            0.01914    0.02826   0.677   0.4981  
treatment      0.60748    1.12199   0.541   0.5882  
age:treatment -0.03893    0.03850  -1.011   0.3119  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.5315) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 72.238  on 57  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 66.874  on 54  degrees of freedom
AIC: 342.18

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.532 
          Std. Err.:  0.373 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -332.180
```

I was expecting to obtain the same result from both of the methods.

**How can i access the regression estimates of `intearaction_nbm`?**

**why are the outcomes different?** According to `intearaction_nbm` i should include the interaction term (the AIC is lower) but according to `ngbinmodel_int` i should not include the interaction term (AIC increases).

**would discretizing my continuous variable `age` be advised?**

Comment: Most of your questions are related to statistics, so this question might be better suited for cross validated.

Answer (score 0):

Remark: You should move this post to cross validated.

1. *How can i access the regression estimates of intearaction_nbm?*

`intearaction_nbm` gives you the result of the addition of **single term** to your model, if you print it, you will have a row per possible additional term (`age:treatment`, `age:another_variable`, etc.) giving you the AIC and P-value among other things.

2. *why are the outcomes different?*

Not possible to answer without the data, but what I would do is define both models and compare their AIC using: `AIC(model_1, model_2)`. This way I am sure that I am comparing the same quantity. As you know, the AIC is defined up to an additional term, and unless you check how it is computed, you cannot be sure that two different functions in two different packages use the same definition.

3. *would discretizing my continuous variable age be advised?*

Not possible to answer without the data...

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the dataset `quine` and the following model with only main effects for `Eth` and `Lrn` factors:

```
library(MASS)

negbin_no_int <- glm.nb(Days ~ Eth + Lrn, data = quine)
summary(negbin_no_int)

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)   3.0367     0.1334  22.764  < 2e-16 ***
# EthN         -0.5520     0.1597  -3.457 0.000546 ***
# LrnSL         0.0388     0.1611   0.241 0.809661

extractAIC(negbin_no_int)

# [1]    3.000 1112.576
```

The model with the interaction term between the two factor is:

```
negbin_with_int <- glm.nb(Days ~ Eth * Lrn, data = quine)
summary(negbin_with_int)

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)   2.9218     0.1503  19.446   <2e-16 ***
# EthN         -0.3374     0.2100  -1.607    0.108    
# LrnSL         0.2929     0.2307   1.269    0.204    
# EthN:LrnSL   -0.4956     0.3201  -1.549    0.122

extractAIC(negbin_with_int)
# [1]    4.000 1112.196
```

The statistical significance of the interaction term is `p=0.122`.
Now we compare the two models using `addterm`:

```
interaction_nbm <- addterm(negbin_no_int, . ~ . + Eth:Lrn, test="Chisq")
print(interaction_nbm)

# Model:
# Days ~ Eth + Lrn
#         Df    AIC    LRT Pr(Chi)
# <none>     1112.6               
# Eth:Lrn  1 1112.2 2.3804  0.1229
```

The AICs given by `addterm` are the same calculated using `extractAIC`.

If you want to see the regression estimates of `addterm`, you can add a `summary(print(nfit))` inside the function, as follows:

```
myaddterm <- function (object, scope, scale = 0, test = c("none", "Chisq"), 
    k = 2, sorted = FALSE, trace = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (missing(scope) || is.null(scope)) 
        stop("no terms in scope")
    if (!is.character(scope)) 
        scope <- add.scope(object, update.formula(object, scope))
    if (!length(scope)) 
        stop("no terms in scope for adding to object")
    ns <- length(scope)
    ans <- matrix(nrow = ns + 1L, ncol = 2L, dimnames = list(c("<none>", 
        scope), c("df", "AIC")))
    ans[1L, ] <- extractAIC(object, scale, k = k, ...)
    n0 <- nobs(object, use.fallback = TRUE)
    env <- environment(formula(object))
    for (i in seq_len(ns)) {
        tt <- scope[i]
        if (trace) {
            message(gettextf("trying + %s", tt), domain = NA)
            utils::flush.console()
        }
        nfit <- update(object, as.formula(paste("~ . +", tt)), 
            evaluate = FALSE)
        nfit <- try(eval(nfit, envir = env), silent = TRUE)
        print(summary(nfit))
        ans[i + 1L, ] <- if (!inherits(nfit, "try-error")) {
            nnew <- nobs(nfit, use.fallback = TRUE)
            if (all(is.finite(c(n0, nnew))) && nnew != n0) 
                stop("number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?")
            extractAIC(nfit, scale, k = k, ...)
        }
        else NA_real_
    }
    dfs <- ans[, 1L] - ans[1L, 1L]
    dfs[1L] <- NA
    aod <- data.frame(Df = dfs, AIC = ans[, 2L])
    o <- if (sorted) 
        order(aod$AIC)
    else seq_along(aod$AIC)
    test <- match.arg(test)
    if (test == "Chisq") {
        dev <- ans[, 2L] - k * ans[, 1L]
        dev <- dev[1L] - dev
        dev[1L] <- NA
        nas <- !is.na(dev)
        P <- dev
        P[nas] <- MASS:::safe_pchisq(dev[nas], dfs[nas], lower.tail = FALSE)
        aod[, c("LRT", "Pr(Chi)")] <- list(dev, P)
    }
    aod <- aod[o, ]
    head <- c("Single term additions", "\nModel:", deparse(formula(object)))
    if (scale > 0) 
        head <- c(head, paste("\nscale: ", format(scale), "\n"))
    class(aod) <- c("anova", "data.frame")
    attr(aod, "heading") <- head
    aod
}
interaction_nbm1 <- myaddterm(negbin_no_int, . ~ . + Eth:Lrn, test="Chisq")
```

The output is:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = Days ~ Eth + Lrn + Eth:Lrn, data = quine, init.theta = 1.177546225, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5770  -1.0470  -0.3645   0.3521   2.7227  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.9218     0.1503  19.446   <2e-16 ***
EthN         -0.3374     0.2100  -1.607    0.108    
LrnSL         0.2929     0.2307   1.269    0.204    
EthN:LrnSL   -0.4956     0.3201  -1.549    0.122    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.1775) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 182.93  on 145  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 168.18  on 142  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1114.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.178 
          Std. Err.:  0.146 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -1104.196
```